# Insert to database and select value

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I want to insert data to table but i must get first 'rid' from this table and increment. I have sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_items (rid, item_id, user_id, x, y, amount, item_value) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) SELECT MAX(rid)+1 as rid FROM users_items
```

What is wrong with this SQL query?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use auto-increment?

Comment: *"What is wrong with this sql query?"*  Possible a hard to debug Race Condition(s) will happen most likely with that SQL code ... Like @Jonnix suggested use a auto-increment and if you need to select it after insert use SELECT [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)..

Comment: You cannot mix VALUES and SELECT syntax in MySQL. At least not in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

It sounds like you're trying to build your own [auto-increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). The commenters have pointed out that this isn't a great idea. *Probably* you can just use the built-in auto-increment feature, and if you can you should. Since it sounds like `rid` is an ID field for the table, this is certainly the way to go.

If you do need to insert values based on values that already exist, that is totally possible. Don't use the below snippet, but depending what you're trying to accomplish the syntax in question might be useful.

```sql
INSERT INTO users_items (rid, item_id, user_id, x, y, amount, item_value)
    SELECT 
        MAX(rid) + 1 as rid,
        ? as item_id,
        ? as user_id,
        ? as x,
        ? as y,
        ? as amount,
        ? as item_value
    FROM 
        users_items
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Auto-increment property in the column "rid". When you set it this way, you don't have to specify the "rid" in the query.

However, if you have to make it by first selecting the last "rid", you have to put the "SELECT" statement in the insert, like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_items (rid, item_id, user_id, x, y, amount, item_value) 
VALUES( (SELECT MAX(rid) + 1 FROM users_items FIRST), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Regards.